# Facing Issue to configure WebDriver with selenium in Pychar

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

My Script is failing to access or load the browser with WebDriver with Selenium in PyCharm using Python.

issue 1: Chrome browser version has been updated to 120.0.6099.130 but the selenium WebDriver Version available is 120.0.6099.109
How to overcome this issue?

Issue 2: even though I have installed the same Edge browser and WebDriver version 120.0.2210.91, my code is failing to launch the browser.

Versions installed

```
Selenium 4.16.1
Python:3.12.1
Chrome browser version 120.0.6099.130 (Downloaded WebDriver Versions 120.0.6099.109)
edge browser version 120.0.2210.91 (Downloaded WebDriver Versions 120.0.2210.91)
Firefox browser version 121.0 (Downloaded WebDriver latest available Versions 0.33.0)
```

The code is failing for all the above browsers, and the Error is getting as shown in the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRjRH.png)

I have tried to launch multiple browsers, but my code is failing to access all the browser.

Expected: the code should run successfully and should be able to launch the browser and access the get URL link

Comment: Can anyone please guide on the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and I solved the problem by using this code. You can give a try this.

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```